# mysql query queue?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a multiplayer game which have started to generate some strange errors as more and more players have singed up.

There's about 1.5 million queries to the database/hour, and I think the problem is that some queries getting executed before some other queries have completed, since I didn't have any problems before, and I getting more and more as more people sign up.

I have two main classes: "sendTurn.php", and "removePlayer.php". If a player have taken to long to respond, he's kicked out. But I guess that problem is what happens if a player make his turn, just as he's being kicked out?

I read somewhere that the queries are put in a queue, but since it require several querys in each class to complete it, is it possible that when, for example, "sendTurn.php" is halfway done (done the first 1-2 queries) that the other class "removePlayer.php" will start to execute its queries?

In this case, what can I do?

Edit:

I use apace2 on a debian VPS server, with phpmyadmin

Comment: What kind of API are you using? mysql, mysqli, mysql-pdo?

Comment: How about wrapping those queries in a transaction?

Comment: thanks for reply. I use apace2 on a debian VPS server, with phpmyadmin

Comment: Is there any performance penalty for transaction?

Comment: What is the name of the php functions you use to connect to the database and perform queries?

Comment: I use $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password!");

Comment: I would recommend changing to mysqli or mysql_pdo, read more here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a real solution would be a full architecture review, since this is more of an architecture question rather than a technical one. It's possible you can avoid this issue altogether but there is not enough information for me to use. However you *could* lock the sensitive tables whenever they are accessed for the full extent of their sensitive process. There will be a performance hit when a lot of players try to reach the same functions, but at least it will work.

For example for such a function

```
*LOCK TABLE*
Do queries
Do queries
Do queries
Do queries
*UNLOCK TABLE*
```

MYSQL example: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html